# IBM IAM IamAuthenticator getToken is not a function

Tags: authentication, ibm-cloud, node-modules, ibm-watson, ibm-iam

I'm trying to get a token to use IBM Watson Speech-to-Text in my app. Here's my code:

```js
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-cloud-sdk-core');

const authenticator = new IamAuthenticator({
    apikey: 'myApiKey',
  });

  authenticator.getToken(function (err, token) {
    if (!token) {
      console.log('error: ', err);
    } else {
      // use token
    }
  });
```

The error message is `authenticator.getToken is not a function`.

The [documentation](https://ibm.github.io/dotnet-sdk-core/docs/master/html/d1/dfd/class_i_b_m_1_1_cloud_1_1_s_d_k_1_1_core_1_1_authentication_1_1_iam_1_1_iam_authenticator.html) says:

```
string IBM.Cloud.SDK.Core.Authentication.Iam.IamAuthenticator.GetToken  (       )
```

I've tried both `getToken` and `GetToken`. Same error message. The code isn't complicated, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what you are trying was possible with V3 and V4 of the SDK, but with V5 the functionality was refactored so that you don't need to require `ibm-cloud-sdk-core`. If you do want to retain that functionality then you need to install a back version of `ibm-cloud-sdk-core`, but it will be incompatible with the latest version of the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me with the latest `ibm-watson` [node-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk),

Install node-sdk with this command

```
npm install --save ibm-watson
```

Then, use this code snippet in your `app.js` or `server.js` node file to receive the IAM access token

```
const watson = require('ibm-watson/sdk');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

// to get an IAM Access Token
const authorization = new watson.AuthorizationV1({
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey: '<apikey>' }),
  url: ''
});

authorization.getToken(function (err, token) {
  if (!token) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('token: ', token);
  }
});
```

You can also directly use the IamAuthenticator with Speech to Text

```
const fs = require('fs');
const SpeechToTextV1 = require('ibm-watson/speech-to-text/v1');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

const speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey: '<apikey>' }),
  url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/'
});

const params = {
  // From file
  audio: fs.createReadStream('./resources/speech.wav'),
  contentType: 'audio/l16; rate=44100'
};

speechToText.recognize(params)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

// or streaming
fs.createReadStream('./resources/speech.wav')
  .pipe(speechToText.recognizeUsingWebSocket({ contentType: 'audio/l16; rate=44100' }))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./transcription.txt'));
```

Answer (score 1):

See my answer in your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60705141/5494819) that might help. You use `BearerTokenAuthenticator` if you want to manage the token authentication process yourself.